# Give feedback to users abusing "not-an-answer" flag

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, voting, not-an-answer

I don't use the flag review queue very often, by today I did and came across several cases where I:

- Flagged the prior `not-an-answer` flag as invalid
- Downvoted the answer because I believe it to be wrong

Can we please have a special review action for this case (flag improperly used to rate correctness of otherwise well-written answer) that gives some sort of feedback to the flag originator?  I'm thinking of a notification to the user once he (or she) accumulates a certain number of these invalid flag countervotes, whether for the same flag or different ones.

[There's a related good idea about providing additional text in the flag UI to help such users, which sadly isn't implemented.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202343/add-a-deactivated-wrong-answer-flag-option)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mods *do* have an action for this, it is declining with the comment of:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

If/when that flag ends up being reviewed by a mod, they can decline with that action.

Comment: Can we make that available to 20k users, instead of just simple "flag is invalid"?  Oftentimes a 20k user has more expertise with the topic and better able to spot that technical inaccuracies might be the cause of the flag.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's going to be reviewed by a mod eventually for NAA flags, so you're already making it clear to that mod that you feel this flag isn't appropriate.  Given that information, the mod is likely to be able to figure out why the flag isn't right.

Comment: Ok.... is there a list of all the possible flag resolutions somewhere?  I haven't seen most of them on my own flags...

Comment: Not that I know of.  There's this one, then "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it", and then just custom reasons.