# Why is my StackExchange OpenID so hard to find?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, login, usability, stack-exchange-openid

With the [new login process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216156/) in meta.SO, I would prefer to login manually via my OpenID rather than enter my username/password combo. As a result, I was looking for **my StackExchange OpenID URL**, and only found it listed in my data.SE profile. It would be nice it if was shown to me on all my profiles, especially since data.SE has different session handling.

Here is the OpenID input I am referring to:
[image: OpenID Form]

> Simply entering the OpenID endpoint(https://openid.stackexchange.com) does not auto-login for me, as show below(albeit very roughly):

[image: OpenID UX]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. "Log in with Stack Exchange" *is* the SE OpenID option. Granted, you do need a username/password to sign into that, but that's no different than logging into, say, Gmail.

Comment: (Also, that link just goes to the question list on MSO. Did you mean to link to a specific question instead?)

Comment: @AnnaLear Semantically speaking, you are referring to the new `#se-login` DOM element, which replaces the existing `.stack_exchange openid_large_btn` DOM element. I am referring to the `#openid_identifier` DOM element, which accepts the OpenID URL.

Comment: You talk about manual OpenID, not Stack Exchange OpenID. And no, it's not hard to find you just need to click "More login options".

Comment: @ShadowWizard The question is how to find my Stack Exchange OpenID **URL**, not finding the form input. I'll emphasize that in the question.

Comment: What you need it for, @Paul? Why not click the big button saying "Log in using Stack Exchange"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The only thing that comes to mind is if he wants to use his SE account to login to a bunch of other sites that use OpenID login; to use SE has his one OpenID account everywhere instead of Google or Facebook or whatever.

Comment: Not that this is necessarily "easy to find", but on [https://openid.stackexchange.com](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), it mentions the endpoint is `https://openid.stackexchange.com/` (you can also just enter `https://stackexchange.com`).

Comment: @ShadowWizard There's the rub. The button is no longer there on meta.SO. That's the underlying usability issue; the button is apparently going away as part of the [new login process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216156/) coming soon to the other sites.

Comment: @PaulSweatte yes it's there, even in your screenshot. No idea how, but you just missed it. [Here is the same screenshot, with the button circled in red](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dswQZ.png)

Comment: @TimStone My point exactly. The URL in question is buried on that page as well, if you click "Use your own URL to log in".

Comment: Right, so [the Stack Exchange login entry](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vuhAm.png) should probably just link to https://openid.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TimStone How does data.SE display the OpenID in the `vcard` table?

Comment: I'm not sure what more to say other than that it just does. What do you need the full URL for anyway? The only useful information is really the endpoint.

Comment: @TimStone If I enter https://openid.stackexchange.com into the field and click the button, it goes to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login. If I enter my OpenID URL, I am actually logged in without entering my username/password, which is the whole point.

Comment: Hm, it works as expected for me, I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: @TimStone I've added an ugly animated gif up above to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Fixed the gif animation via LiceCAP.

Answer (score 5):

I see there is an option to create a custom OpenID now, via the following process:

- Go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login
- Login
- Click the `Edit Profile` link
- Enter the vanity URL where the `john.smith (optional)` ghost text is shown

Click `Update` to generate a Vanity URL, such as:

https://openid.stackexchange.com/john.milton

Other sites which allow the use of any OpenID provider:

- http://www.open-bio.org
- https://www.openstreetmap.org
- https://opencongress.org
- https://wiki.videolan.org

Answer (score 3):

To make the issue clearer, one problem with the change is that on has to manually log in to this form, even if already logged in to openid.SE. This creates an extra step which wasn't there before.

Answer (score 1):

Login to the Stack Exchange OpenID and click the link "Use your own URL to login" to show your OpenID.

[image: Successful login to Stack Exchange OpenID]

[image: Your Stack Exchange OpenID]

Comment: I could not easily find this info anywhere else. Thanks.