# Use the login on StackExchange.com in other SE sites

Tags: support, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid, authentication

I am logged in on StackExchange.com, I want to login on another SE site without entering a password. Why do I have to choose a third party provider?

Isn't using cookies possible for subdomains? I see they are set either for `stackexchange.com` or for `.stackexchange.com`.

If SE wants to use OpenID instead, why isn't the global account an OpenID account too? It seems I'd have to enter https://openid.stackexchange.com as OpenID provider, but I never logged in or registered there so I'd need a password.

Comment: Because you haven't created an account on that site. Just use the same details you did for SE.

Comment: I didn't ask about autologin, I asked about login in general. I know autologin is supposed to work when I already registered in a site. And, by the way, no, I can't login with my original method, because Google.

Comment: Hu? What did you log in with last time?

Comment: That's really offtopic here...

Comment: Wha...? I'm trying to work out the issue? What did you sign in with to SE?

Comment: And I'm grateful. :) But my issue is that I want to use the third party providers as little as possible. (The Google issue has been solved in the meanwhile, I see. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254141/248268 )

Comment: Okay... http://stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent and add another option (i.e. SE) to your account. Then you can sign in with that everywhere?

Comment: Ah, thanks. But then if I choose SE it asks me my SE email and password... which I don't have. I'll try but that will destroy the test case. :)

Comment: I see. Okay, sign into the new site by creating a SE login. Then merge them, and then you can delete the social media one.

Comment: I registered by email and password as well (which logged me in my usual account) and then I added the method at http://stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent but when I visit a new SE site the SE login still asks me email and password. The difference is that https://openid.stackexchange.com now recognises me and I can select "Other login options" and enter https://openid.stackexchange.com . That works, without entering password again, but feels harder than it should be.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then, sorry.

Comment: In the end I think my problem is the same as this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221048/why-is-my-stackexchange-openid-so-hard-to-find Let's dupe.