# better error message for "Illegal email address"

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, login

I recently got an "Illegal email address" error message when attempting to log in to Mathematics Stack Exchange for the first time from Firefox.  The problem turned out to be that the automatic form-completing software in Firefox had filled in the field where my email address should have gone with my name instead.  And my name, indeed, is not a legal email address.  But it took me a while to figure out the problem.

I would have figured out the problem quicker if the error message had specified what the email address in question actually was, as in

```
Illegal email address: "Lyle Ramshaw"
```

or perhaps

```
"Lyle Ramshaw" is not a legal email address.
```

Comment: Is there another email address field you confused it with?

Comment: How are you logging in? What OpenId provider?

Comment: @Servy: If you don't see the placeholder text (because your browser auto-filled the field), it's not really obvious that *any* of the otherwise unlabeled fields are meant to be filled with an e-mail address.

Answer (score 5):

I have to disagree. The error is perfectly clear and located right above the field:

> [image]

Adding what you typed to the error message is just extra noise.

Comment: I guess the problem is that, if your browser is auto-filling that field, you'll never see the placeholder text that tells you that it *is* supposed to be filled with an e-mail address rather than just some generic username. Having the message "right above the field" doesn't really help, since that happens to also be the obvious location for *any* error message. Maybe the field itself could be restyled e.g. with a red border to highlight it?

Answer (score 4):

This issue should be fixed once the [new login interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216156/new-login-signup-pathway-for-the-stack-exchange-network) (currently in use here on Meta) is fully deployed.  The new login form defines the e-mail field with [type="email`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.email.html), causing modern browsers to auto-validate it:

[image: Screenshot of new SE login form with invalid e-mail address]